# How to set a new includePath in application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework2, include-path

I am using Zend framework 2 and i am trying to make a Custom includePath in the application.ini file.
The includePath should include all the files in the selected folder and all files in all it's subfolders.

I already have

```
 includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models"
```

but this only includes the files in the models folder and not the files in the models subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ZF2 there are no application-level models, every model should be part of a `Module`. After that, every Module knows how and where to load their own models and you can set specific paths for models if really necessary in `module.config.php`.

There are more details about `Modules` in official zf2 [documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.0.3/user-guide/modules.html).